# What to use for storage in an Ionic 4 PWA app?

Tags: storage, ionic4, progressive-web-apps

I’m using Ionic 4 to build a PWA. It's supposed to work from the browser only (so far) and used mostly on mobile devices with offline capabilities. I’ve been using ionic storage so far and it works fine on the desktop browser and on the my android device. Not on iphones however. I read that this is a know issue. So I’m looking for a solution that would actually be cross-platform. Is there something I could use that works on android, ios and desktop browsers?

Cordova wouldn't be a solution since it won't work on web.

The first thing I need is to store the access token when logging in. From there I think I'll be able to figure it out.

Comment: I use Ionic storage with an Ionic3 app.  I haven't had any issues with iOS on mobile or web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When running in the web or as a Progressive Web App, Storage will attempt to use IndexedDB, WebSQL, and localstorage, in that order.
>
> - [source](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage)

Ionic Storage will work fine on iOS. All three of those storage engines will run in Safari on iOS. If Ionic Storage isn't working you should report a bug to Ionic or open a question about getting Storage to work.

Comment: Marking as correct as the problem was between the keyboard and chair. The storage was actually working as you said. The problem was that the api did not return the correct response/error which made me think the problem was in the ios storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a database implementation like [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) which is basically a CouchDB adapter. The developers explain on their website:

> PouchDB is an open-source JavaScript database inspired by Apache CouchDB that is designed to run well within the browser.
>
> PouchDB was created to help web developers **build applications that work as well offline as they do online**.
>
> It enables applications to store data locally while offline, then synchronize it with CouchDB and compatible servers when the application is back online, keeping the user's data in sync no matter where they next login.

In one of my company's Ionic 4 projects we use PouchDB to store data for both app and web usage (iOS and browser). You can choose [one of several suitable adapters](https://pouchdb.com/adapters.html) for browser storage as well as on native devices.

Comment: Thank you for this, I will definitely need something like this in the future.